# Magento2 update minicart using custom ajax

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

I have a scenario to update quantity using the +/- button in the magento2 mini-cart.
I override MagentoCheckout to my theme and edited minicart/items/default.html and made the changes, now I need to make an auto-update of price and quantity change on click of the +/- button.

My ajax call on a click

```
function plus(idvl)
        {                  
        fieldName = idvl;                       
        fieldName = fieldName.slice(1);             
        var currentVal = parseInt($('#cart-item-'+fieldName+'-qty').val());                          
        var currentVal = parseInt($('#cart-item-'+fieldName+'-qty').val());        
        if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {                        
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal + 1);                 
            
        vr=new Object();
        vr["item_id"]  = fieldName;
        vr["item_qty"] = currentVal;
        vr["form_key"] = '<?php echo $FormKey->getFormKey();?>';            
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>checkout/sidebar/updateItemQty/',
                dataType: 'json',
                type : 'post',
                data: vr,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));                      
                }
            });         
            
        } else {            
            $('input[name='+fieldName+']').val(0);
        } 
        }
```

Now the ajax call works and it returns status 200K {success: true} but the contents are not updated. is there any way to achieve it?

After updateItemQty ajax call, there is another call which works if I directly clicking on the update button in the mini cart like

```
customer/section/load/?sections=cart%2Cmessages&update_section_id=true&_=12
```

But I'm not sure how this one is triggered in the core code. Any help is appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The cart should be automagically updated due to the 'ajaxComplete' event (listened for in the customer-data.js file). Can you check if this js module is loaded? If this is triggered, verify in the `sectionConfig.getAffectedSections(settings.url)` method if the response contains the cart section.

Otherwise you can update the minicart manually like this:

```
if (res.minicart) {
    $(self.options.minicartSelector).replaceWith(res.minicart);
    $(self.options.minicartSelector).trigger('contentUpdated');
}
```

Comment: customer-data.js is not loaded in the viewsource of the page. If i included it directly in the Magento_theme js its getting some console error and the minicart stops working.

Comment: I referred in google that to add this script but not sure in which phtml we need to add it , i tried adding it in footer section but its not working. <script>
    require([
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
    ], function (customerData) {
        var sections = ['cart'];
        customerData.invalidate(sections);
    });
</script>

Comment: The customer-data.js shouldnt be visible in the source because it is lazy loaded using requirejs.  You should see if it is loaded by using the web-inspector. Normally the minicart.js depends on it like this :
    define([
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'underscore',
        'sidebar',
        'mage/translate'
    ], function (Component, customerData, $, ko, _) {